# In android studio how can i take input in EditText field as a number eg; 1452 and convert it into integer array{1,4,5,2}

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I want to sort an array. I am not able to figure out how to take input from edittext field and convert single digits into array.

Comment: convert the integer to a string, then extract each character from the string, converting each character to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your String from your EditText and then store each number into an array using a for loop.

```
public class EditTextArray extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_text_array);

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et.setText("1452");  // Normally user input here...

        String text = et.getText().toString();

        int[] array = new int[text.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            array[i] = Character.getNumericValue(text.charAt(i));
        }

        Log.d("Output: ", Arrays.toString(array));
        //09-20 14:27:45.272 20400-20400/com.jtwaller.test D/Output:: [1, 4, 5, 2]

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            sb.append(array[i] + " ");
        }

        Log.d("Output: ", sb);
        //09-20 14:27:45.272 20400-20400/com.jtwaller.test D/Output:: 1 4 5 2 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! You are lifesaver. Any possibility i can get that array without brackets and comas.!??

Comment: See my edited answer above.  I do hope you're trying to code these things yourself.

If my answer has been helpful please accept my answer by clicking the grey checkmark below the up and down arrows of my submission.

Comment: Thanks Bro! Works Perfectly! As being new user can't vote your answer actually!

Answer (score 0):

well first do

```
String s = yourEditText.toString();
Integer digitNumber = s.length();
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(s);
```

then ull have to read single digits u do this by using the Mod operator so

```
new Integer[] I = new Integer[digitNumber];
for(int i=0; i<digitNumber;i++){
    I[i] = i % 10;
    i = i/10;
}
```

Comment: Is this right?i m trying for insertion sort
public void iSort(int[] a) {
        String text = input.getText().toString();
        int[] array = new int[text.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {// n is length
            array[i] = Integer.valueOf(text.charAt(i));
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <n; j++) {
            int key = array[j];
            int i = j - 1;
            while ((i > -1) && (array[i] > key)) {
                array[i + 1] = array[i];
                i--;
            }
            array[i + 1] = key;
            printnumbers(array);

Comment: äm what does `int[a]` even do there?

Answer (score 0):

Just do like so... get your String and convert it with parseInt

```
String number = "10";
int result = Integer.parseInt(number);
```